# .dll Loaded but entry-point 'DllRegisterServer' was not found

Tags: dll, windows-7, cygwin, entrypointnotfoundexcept

Missing .dll file, after downloading i placed it in system32 folder then I run command regsvr32 with the name of the DLL. But it gives me an error, now the error is:

The module 'cygwin1.dll' was loaded but the entry-point 'DllRegisterServer' was not found.

Make sure that 'cygwin1.dll' or 'libstdc++-6' is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again

Answer (score -1):

Try with `.ocx`

for example if you want to register `BIDIB.dll`

definetely its contains some list of `.ocx`, `.oca`, `.dll` extensed files are there, that time you can register the dll with `.ocx`

Ex: `regsvr32 BIDIB.ocx`

Comment: It didn't work, not with `.ocx`, `.oca` or `.dll`. Any suggestions?